Crossplane ProviderRevision and automatically handling Workload Identities
There exists plenty of documentation on how to handle IAM with GCP and Crossplane, complete with nice details on exactly what commands to run to tie them together with workload identity.
My issue is automation. I use terraform run by GHA to create a kubernetes cluster along with any other GCP resources it needs.
By default the Kubernetes SA the Crossplane provider pod runs as is uniquely named for each version/release of each provider, how do I make automation that's necessarily outside the kubernetes cluster add the GCP IAM bindings to an SA created in the kubernetes cluster with a unique name?
Alternatively, if I create a known named kubernetes SA and have the Crossplane provider pod run as that, how do I ClusterRoleBind that SA to the uniquely name ClusterRole the Crossplane provider also creates? I suppose I could just also create my own ClusterRole and not use any of the RBAC the Crossplane GCP providers create, this would be a lot of toil however.
From https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/upbound/provider-family-gcp/v1.3.0/docs/configuration here are the key two commands to run to allow a kubernetes SA to impersonate a GCP SA with workload identity.
$ gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    ${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member "serviceAccount:${PROJECT_ID}.svc.id.goog[upbound-system/${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}]" \
    --project ${PROJECT_ID}

$ kubectl annotate serviceaccount ${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} \
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    -n upbound-system

${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} either contains the .status.currentRevision field of the currently installed provider, or is your own kubernetes SA with a ClusterRoleBinding to a ClusterRole that contains the .status.currentRevision field of the currently installed provider.

Turns out I was worried much about nothing. Crossplane has your back.
With the following manifests Crossplane takes ownership of the created SA, does the complicated bit of binding the SA to the ClusterRole it creates for that specific revision (I was not aware this would happen automatically), and runs the pod as the SA.
---
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: provider-gcp-network
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-gcp-network:v1.3.0
  runtimeConfigRef:
    name: provider-gcp-network
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: provider-gcp-network
---
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1beta1
kind: DeploymentRuntimeConfig
metadata:
  name: provider-gcp-network
spec:
  serviceAccountTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: provider-gcp-network
---
apiVersion: gcp.upbound.io/v1beta1
kind: ProviderConfig
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  projectID: <projectId>
  credentials:
    source: InjectedIdentity

Using a GKE Autopilot cluster I can then bind GCP roles directly onto the Kubernetes SA and create GCP resources with it.
principal://iam.googleapis.com/projects/<projectNumber>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<projectId>.svc.id.goog/subject/ns/<kubernetesNamespace/sa/<kubernetesSA>
Everything in the provider-family-gcp documentation relating to currentRevision is, I presume, outdated.

So this description https://docs.upbound.io/providers/provider-gcp/authentication/#workload-identity is outdated?
Im woundering about the field "runtimeConfigRef" in your description. I only find the field controllerConfigRef in the Provider.pkg.crossplane.io/v1 (https://doc.crds.dev/github.com/crossplane/crossplane/pkg.crossplane.io/Provider/v1@v1.4.1)
I'm currenlty strugling to get my stuff running using the workloadIdenity, somehow my providers do not use the service-account I try to provide them.

v1.4.1 is very old. Crossplane is currently at v1.16.0
https://doc.crds.dev/github.com/crossplane/crossplane/pkg.crossplane.io/Provider/v1 has runtimeConfigRef.
https://docs.upbound.io/providers/provider-gcp/authentication/#workload-identity is also currently outdated. The ControllerConfig CRD has been deprecated, as of Crossplane 1.14 I believe.
Also, like I said, this might be a GKE Autopilot thing but I do not need a GCP SA at all, the GCP roles necessary can be bound directly onto the Kubernetes SA with a principal:// reference.

Well now I fixed the issue. My problem was that my cluster, where crossplane is running didn't have the Workload Identity Federation enabled, as well as the Nodes.  After I updated the cluster and the nodes. It worked, evenso a little bit differnt than I thought, I don't even need a Workload Identity pool , it seems to work du to the GKE-Metadata feature of the cluster, when I understood it correcctly. (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to)
